# start/stop two apache servers on same machine

Tags: linux, apache

We have a linux machine on which we have two instances of apache servers installed in different directories and running on different ports. Both have httpd.conf (with same name). PID for both is also named httpd.pid. When i restart httpd service, the one running on port 80 gets restarted. But I need to restart the other one.

they both have their own PIDs in different directories. both are named named httpd.pid. I renamed the one on port 80 to httpd_1 and fired **service httpd restart** command thinking that it would restart the other one. But it didn't. It returned error. 
Both the servers are running fine. I just made some changes to httpd.conf for the server on port 8099 which is running a Oracle EBS app. So I need to restart it for the changes to take effect.
The server admin has been restarting it somehow, but I'm not in a position to ask him how it's done.

Comment: so change the name of the pid files, or put them in different directories. if they're BOTH writing to the same pid file, then you'll never be able to tell which is which.

Comment: Why would one want to execute _two_ apache http servers on a single system?

Comment: @sidekickbottom, You should build two virtual machines that each one know the other, running application twice on the same machine is bad practice. sorry, let face it.

Comment: each one probably has a different init/startup script. so you just need to find the correct script to restart the second instance.  also there are lots of ways to restart apache, such as kill -USR1  `cat /path/to/pid`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

As said, you need to make sure they are using separate everythings.  Otherwise you may as well just have one Apache instance listening on multiple ports with name based virtual hosts...

In /etc/apache2/envars look for the locations of your pid file, etc.